# Sorting my spacing from copying listbox data

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am using the below code to copy data from a listbox:

```
 Dim sData As String
Dim X As Integer

'Has the user ticked the use col heads tick box?
    If Me.ChkColHeads = True Then
        sData = sData & "Account Number" & vbTab & "Advisor Name" & vbTab & vbTab & "Team" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "Days Lost" & vbTab & vbTab & vbCrLf
    End If

'x would be set to row 1 if using column heading in list
    For X = 0 To Me.List31.ListCount
        If Me.List31.Selected(X) = True Then
            sData = sData & Me.List31.Column(0, X) & vbTab & vbTab & Me.List31.Column(1, X) & vbTab & vbTab & Me.List31.Column(2, X) & vbTab & vbTab & Me.List31.Column(3, X) & vbTab & vbTab & Me.List31.Column(4, X) & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next
'Copy the data to the clipboard

    ClipBoard_SetData (sData)

'Let user know that the procedure has been completed

    MsgBox "Data copied to clipboard", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Copied"
```

There is also a module that copies it to the clipboard.

My issue it the formatting - Some items are not lined up as they should be as below:

```
 11111      Name1       Team1       0        
22222       Name1       Team2               
33333       Name1       Team3       5       
22222       Name1       Team1       6        
1121        Name1       Team3       0       
543     Name1       Team3            
7654        Name1                       Team4               
432543      Name1       Team7   0        
87654       Name1       Team1   3
```

Some teams are not lined up and can not figure out why. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you use vbTab. But that is correct if you wish to paste the date into, say, Excel.

If you wish text and spaces only, do:

```
Left(Me.List31.Column(0, X) & Space(16), 20)
```

or similar. Adjust 16 and 20 to your liking.